# i have problem with converting function in class component to functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-functional-component

from this function, How can I convert "this.state" to use in functional.

```
  const handleDayClick = (day) => {
        const range = DateUtils.addDayToRange(day, this.state);
        setRange(range)
    }
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: You have to either use hooks (useState) or convert your state into props.

Comment: we can not use this pointer in functional component so you have to use hooks(useState)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `useState` like this

```js
const [range, setRange] = useState({});
```

then you need to use another variable name in the handle function.

```js
const handleDayClick = (day) => {
    const newRange = DateUtils.addDayToRange(day, range);
    setRange(newRange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**this** pointer doesn’t work in functional component and you have to use hooks, so add this line

```
const [range, setRange] = React.useState({});
```

Then change **this.state** to **range**